# Reversing the order of rows and operation efficiency

Tags: python, pandas

I know that to reverse the order of rows in a pandas data frame that I can use

```
df = df.iloc[::-1]
```

but my issue is doing more operations with it. For instance,

```
def transform (x) :
    x = x.iloc[::-1]
    x['a'] = x['a'] * 2
    return x
```

for

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'a' : np.arange(5), 'b' : np.arange(5)})
```

is incredibly slow - a timeit benchmark gives 175 milliseconds on my machine, but if I replace the multiplication step by a loop then it is fast (191 microseconds), i.e.

```
def transform (x) :
    x = x.iloc[::-1]
    for i in range(x.shape[0]) : 
        x['a'].values[i] = x['a'].values[i] * 2
    return x
```

I'm willing to use the second function (even if the first is more 'elegant'), but I'm wondering for the future what is the best way to reverse the order of rows without comprimising efficiency and why this behaviour happens.

Thanks!

EDIT: I've added some more code to help - I'm basically trying to understand what the difference between these functions are:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

y = pd.DataFrame({'a' : np.arange(5), 'b' : np.arange(5)})

def transform_1 (x) : 
    x = x.iloc[::-1]
    x['a'] = x['a'] * 2
def transform_2 (x) :
    x = x.iloc[::-1]
    for i in range(x.shape[0]) :
        x['a'].values[i] = x['a'].values[i] * 2

%timeit transform_1(y.copy())
%timeit transform_2(y.copy())

39.9 ms ± 614 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
238 µs ± 5.19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Long story short, I have a function that takes some data frames as input, but for a specific case I want to pass the data frames reversed with a particular transformation (analogous to multiplying by 2), but I noticed that the function was far slower than usual. I'm trying to understand why reversing a data frame and then trying to apply a transformation is so slow.

EDIT 2:

```
def transform_3 (x) :
    x = x.iloc[::-1]
    x['a'] *= 2
def transform_4 (x) :
    x = x.sort_index(axis = 0, ascending = False)
    x['a'] = x['a'] * 2

%timeit transform_3(y.copy())
%timeit transform_4(y.copy())
41.1 ms ± 1.19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
536 µs ± 9.91 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Your given example would work the same way if you just did `x['a'] *= 2`, i.e. iterating forwards. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I've made an edit - hopefully it makes my question a bit clearer. I've also tested your suggestion and I have the same issues with speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure that I understand what you're trying to do, but I'm going by the example you used in your question

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'a' : np.arange(5), 'b' : np.arange(5)})
```

Result (first column is the index):

```
|    |   a |   b |
|----|-----|-----|
|  0 |   0 |   0 |
|  1 |   1 |   1 |
|  2 |   2 |   2 |
|  3 |   3 |   3 |
|  4 |   4 |   4 |
```

Next, we call your function (either version of `transform`)

```
transform(x)
```

Result:

```
|    |   a |   b |
|----|-----|-----|
|  0 |   0 |   0 |
|  1 |   2 |   1 |
|  2 |   4 |   2 |
|  3 |   6 |   3 |
|  4 |   8 |   4 |
```

So basically you reversed the order of the rows before doing your calculation, but the result would've been the same if you didn't.

In any case, you can also use `sort_values` to reverse the table without looping through it.

```
x.rename_axis(index='idx').sort_values(by='idx', 
                                       axis=0, 
                                       ascending=False)
```

As you have to pass the name of the index level to `sort_values`, you first have to call `rename_axis` to assign a name (can be anything, I chose `idx` for this example).

Alternatively, you can also use `sort_index` (the performance is similar):

```
x.sort_index(axis='index', ascending=False)
```

Thus:

```
def transform_simple(x) :
    x['a'] *= 2
    return x

x = pd.DataFrame({'a' : np.arange(500), 'b' : np.arange(500)})
transform_simple(x.sort_index(axis='index', ascending=False))
```

Timing result (500 rows):

```
transform (1st version): 81.9 ms ± 2.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
transform (2nd version): 4.23 ms ± 319 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
transform_simple: 1.55 ms ± 147 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - would it be possible for you to also explain why the first function is slower? I've included an edit to hopefully show what I mean better. Basically I have more complicated transformations I'm interested in and I'd like to know what I can do ensure that there is no loss in efficiency in reversing the data frame. For instance, yours runs 541 µs on mine (I had to use sort_index instead),  but I don't know why transform_2 (in edit) runs faster.

Comment: `sort_index` is actually a good alternative and probably negates the necessity to first name the index. Why `transform_2` is so much faster than `transform`? I have no idea, I would have expected looping operation to be *much* slower.

Comment: It's been a week and there's been no new answer so I've accepted this. I was hoping to gain some more insight into why x.iloc[::-1] interferes so much with basic operations but I'm satisfied with a solution at the very least. Thanks!